# CAS: How can i manage stand alone services in CAS?

Tags: rest, cas

I took a look at many examples how I can use the RESTful API in order to communicate with the CAS server from my stand alone CAS client. At the beginning I thought that I simply don't need a service URL since my stand alone app does not have an URL. But when I saw the examples I realized that I need to send the service URL and as far as I see, it is also needed for a callback from the CAS server to the CAS stand alone client.

How can I give me stand alone app and URL that it can deal with the RESTful API?

EDIT: As I found out in my other question, the client just pulls the data from the REST web service. So basically it is just an CAS issue. So, how can I solve the problem with the not existing service URL of my stand alone application ? You need a service URL to get the ST for the stand alone application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CAS 4.2.x REST API, you need a URL, but it doesn't have to be real, because CAS won't try to reach it. The URL is just used to identify tickets related to specific services.

To obtain a Service Ticket, two requests are performed, as explained in the official documentation: https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html

1. The first request obtains a Ticket Granting Ticket. Using that one, you can perform the second request. You get the TGT from the CAS response.
2. The second request obtains the actual Service Ticket.

And that's it. There are no requests from CAS to your service.

To check a given service ticket, you just perform a single request to the REST API specifying both the ticket supplied and the URL of the service. The response to that request tells you if the given Service Ticket is valid for the specified service. Once more, no requests from CAS to your service.

In the end, the URL is nothing more than an identifier for your service, using in the generation of the tickets.